# NET USE to Azure file storage: System error 1312

Tags: azure

Azure cloud file storage rocks!

But in my batch file, most (over 75%) of net use commands fail with error:

```
System error 1312 has occurred.

A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.
```

What are we doing?
In our data center, we fire a task every few minutes from a scheduled task. The task is a simple powershell script, that does a "net use" and then a "robocopy." The goal is to have our local data (SQL TLOGs in this case) up in Azure storage, and for Azure to be within 5 min or so of current at all times.

So, this NET USE command, that is a problem, is in the following environment:

- Win2012-R2 virtual machine
- On VMWare ESX
- In our data center

It works sometimes (once every 5-10 iterations).

The net use command is:

```
net use \\my-sharename.file.core.windows.net\myname /u:username <crypto>
```

And we mostly get the System error noted above.

We have tried doing:

```
net use \\my-sharename.file.core.windows.net\myname /delete
net use \\my-sharename.file.core.windows.net\myname /u:username <crypto>
```

but see no change in behavior.

How do we solve?

Comment: Hi Samsmith whare are your running the NET USE commands from? a VM in Azure? a Machine on Prem?

Comment: @samsmith Ever make any progress here? Having the exact same problem trying to write a batch to automatically connect to our storage account(s).

Comment: @CBauer I wish. Answer is no. Issue is wide open, and I have no clue where to turn next.

Comment: Out of curiosity does it work the first time after a restart? I just wrote a batch to auto attach to the share and it worked fine after a restart and haven't had it since.

Comment: @CBauer Not sure, but expect yes. The issue comes and goes... but is mostly present.

Answer (score -2):

you should cahnge /u:username to /u:.\username

Comment: The suggested change /u:.\username gives an error: ( as expected )
The user context supplied is invalid.